# get doctrine to select entities without all associations

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

my user entity has a couple of associations

```
    oneToMany:
    images:
        targetEntity: Image
        mappedBy: user
    posts:
        targetEntity: Post
        mappedBy: user
        fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
    postcomments:
        targetEntity: Postcomment
        mappedBy: user
        fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
```

i want to select a specific user with all his posts and images, but not his postcomments. This is the query I use:

```
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('u', 'p', 'i'))
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.posts', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('u.images', 'i')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
```

However the result returned contains all the other associations aswell. Same as if I just select u and delete the joins.

How can I select only certain associations to be in the result?

Here is the full code of the api call

```
 public function getAction($id)
 {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('u', 'p', 'i'))
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.posts', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('u.images', 'i')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery();

    $users = $db->getOneOrNullResult();
    $view = $this->view($users);

    return $this->handleView($view);
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misled by Doctrine's lazy loading feature.

When you do

```
$user->getPostcomments();
```

and it returns you the collection of `Postcomment`s, it still doesn't mean it has been fetched from DB along with the user itself.

Lazy loading takes place here. It means that it's loaded on the first access attempt to this collection. It's not really fetched until you use it. ;-)

By default Doctrine sets `fetch: LAZY` mode which works as mentioned above. You've used [`EXTRA_LAZY`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) which has some additional features. In this case when you attempt to access particular element of collection (or a slice), Doctrine still won't load whole collection, but only a requested element or subset if `slice()` method it used. That's sometimes useful, but sometimes it may be cause of performance issues. You should be aware of difference between `LAZY` and `EXTRA_LAZY`.

Comment: Thank you for claryfying. However I need to output the result of $qb in an api as json, and it will - no matter if i add the joins or leave them out - always output EVERY related entities associated with user, so basically when i just want to have a json with user and images, i still get of posts, postcomments etc. Even if i just "select u from AppBundle:User" or do a $this->getUser() and output to json I get every other related element in the result which is kind of a huge set of data and annoying. Hence my initial question, how can this be prevented and only the related things be selected?

Comment: Provide the code that shows how you generate json response.

Comment: This show how to fetch data. I asked about code that **generates response**. (P.S. edit you question instead of posting code into comment. It's unreadable)

Comment: aye! just edited. the response is created by $this->handleView($view) from FOSRestBundle

Comment: So this is issue related to this bundle. It apparently invokes `getPostcomments` and then they are fetched from DB. You probably have to configure it to tell how your entities should be serialized.  This is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Good to know it's an issue of the serializer. Then I know where I have to look. Thank you so much!